# android app crashes when moving objects in main.xml

Tags: xml, android-layout

I have a simple application containing a single activity and a single layout. Whenever i'm trying to move an object in the layout to another place either through the graphical editor or through code, the application crashes when compiled and ran. The layout contains 2 labels, a button and a text box, nothing special, I can't understand what is the cause of this.

This is the xml layout i'm using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id= "@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Answer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">      
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>





</LinearLayout>
```

When i'm trying to move the first TextView under EditText, the application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean rebuild. Projects->clean that should probably fix it.

Comment: It didn't help... i'm trying to place TextView under EditBox and the app crashes when i'm trying to run it.